# MySQL Database: Limit user access to data they created

Tags: c#, mysql, permissions

Using C# and MySQL, is it possible to create individual user accounts to access the database, and only allow users to view/modify/delete their own data?

Comment: I guess the idea is hardening the application in case the C# code contains flaws. Therefore it may look like a good idea to establish the database connection as the user. One big problem I see here is, that you cannot just easily pool and reuse database connections like that. The connection of user Joe cannot be reused by user Jane. Establishing the connection on each user request can be costly (even when application and database run on the same system) and can completely stall your server when you are dealing with a lot of simultaneous requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL you can grant privileges for users or user groups to all SIDU access types (Select, Insert, Delete, Update) on Tables and Views.

If you are talking about a finer granularity at the row level, I think you will need to store this information somewhere; the most direct way is to add something like an owner field and/or a privilege field to each Table you need to restrict.

Another way would be be to create one or more Tables which hold keys of restricted or of non-restricted records or contents, like projects or regions..

The first solution would be not terribly hard to code, provided you have a well-designed concept of ownership & privileges, sufficiently flexible both for now and for later on.

You would add a layer of access logic, which adds an extra where clause, in the simplest case like: `..AND WHERE table.ownerID = @ownerid` or the like to every SELECT. And for every INSERT it would fill the field with the current user ID or group ID and/or his current access rights..

Plan for user groups, as one user will often need to do the work of another one, at least partially..

Extra privileges-tables will need even better planning..

Also consider tools & functions to manage these data..

**Update**

Since it is clear now, that you want to set up a Web based data access you could either create separate Tables for each user with the user name or a hash or encrypted version of it, used as a prefix to each Table; or, more common, you can set up a separate DataBase for each user, again, with a DB name somehow derived from the user name or user ID.

The versiom with a separated DB for each user is easier to write, since after the login, everything will work the same for each user, i.e. no need to inject anything into the SQL.

The only possible consideration may come in with technical or monetary restrictions coming from the provider. Some packages only allow for a small number of DataBases. In such a case the Table-prefix method is the next most likely solution.

So the number of users you expect may be a deciding factor, too..

Comment: I'm still a bit confused.. basically, use user gets a copy of my software. In the software, there should be a create user button. That button should create a table named "username_data" or something. From that point on, that user should only be able to query/modify/delete that table. They should not be able to modify/view/delete any other table in the database that they did not create with their username/password.

Comment: OK. What do those users share? The same DataBase?

Comment: Someone commented, then deleted their comment, but mentioned "stored routines" or something. After some quick googling, it sounded like I could have someone log onto the database as a guest, and only have access to one stored routine called "create user" which they could call to create a user and a table, which would be the only thing they had access to from then on... does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, they share the database, but can put their own tables in it

Comment: Will they all use the same Tables? In that case could prefix the Tables with the username or id like: 'bitwise_products' etc.. and use prefexd names in all SQL statements.. I don't know about "stored routines" yet..

Comment: ya, that's basically where I'm at now is just letting a users create tables prefixed with their username, but I have no way to control access so users can't access other user's tables, etc.

Comment: of course this also requires me to bake the password for the database into the app, which is not wise.

Comment: 'no way to control access so users can't access other user's tables' well, if you control the sql you can control access. of course nobody must access the DB outside of your program! Not sure why it would affect the password in any way, though..?

Comment: no one SHOULD access the database outside the program... but, I need to know that what I am doing is hacker-safe

Comment: Am I even going about this the right way? Is it common to simply create 1 database per user? can this be done remotely?

Comment: Well it's a big world, so 'common' is a bit vague.. It is comon that user that share a DB also share their data, I'd say.. One DB per user is usual in Web apps. Where will the DB sit?

Comment: The DB will sit on a webserver

Comment: Ok, my question was not 100% clear, but I wanted to have a user create their data through a mobile app, then  view it online. I was about to embed the database access credentials and account creation/modification into the app itself, but out in the wild, I think that would be foolish. what I think I will do is create a server side script(PHP) which creates an access token and the associated tables with appropriate permissions and returns those to the user. the access token would be the prefix to that users tables, which would be all they could use.

Comment: Anyways, I guess your answer is technically the most correct answer ;)